# Getting one single row from list in java instead of 3 rows?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am coming to an issue where I have a simple API where I am getting data and inside my database I have 3 rows which indicates the rateType. So, with my code below when I do a GET request with localhost:8080/myapp/salaries/1234 I get my rows but it just gives me the first row of my database only.

```
@Entity
@Setter

public class Salary {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "JOB_CLASS_CD")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String jobClassCd;

    @Column(name = "JOB_CLASS_TITLE")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String jobClassTitle;

    @Column(name = "RATE_TYPE")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String rateType;

    @Column(name = "STEP_1")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String step1;

    @Column(name = "STEP_2")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String step2;

    @Column(name = "STEP_3")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String step3;

    @Column(name = "STEP_4")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String step4;

    @Column(name = "STEP_5")
    @JsonSerialize
    private String step5;

}
```

> JsonResults:

```
   [
{

    "jobClassCd": "1234",
     "jobClassTitle": "ADMIN",
      "rateType": "Annual",
    "step1": "  $5555.00",
    "step2": "  $5555.00",
    "step3": "  $5555.00",
    "step4": "  $5555.00",
    "step5": "  $5555.00"


},
{
   "jobClassCd": "1234",
     "jobClassTitle": "ADMIN",
      "rateType": "Annual",
    "step1": "  $5555.00",
    "step2": "  $5555.00",
    "step3": "  $5555.00",
    "step4": "  $5555.00",
    "step5": "  $5555.00"
},
{
   "jobClassCd": "1234",
     "jobClassTitle": "ADMIN",
      "rateType": "Annual",
    "step1": "  $5555.00",
    "step2": "  $5555.00",
    "step3": "  $5555.00",
    "step4": "  $5555.00",
    "step5": "  $5555.00"
}
```

]

Comment: where is your query?

Comment: Please see updated question with the code provided - for you to understand it better.

Comment: Don't mind sharing the display logic too

Comment: I your interface you must have a method like `List<Salary >findByRateType(String rateType)`; then in the service you can convert List to Stream if you like :)

Comment: What you mean the display logic, @Jayr?

Comment: @TinyOS what do you mean?

Comment: @TinyOS can I put the same logic inside my list method `List<Salary> salaries = salaryRepository.findByJobClassCd(rateType);`  ?

Comment: Yes you can but you have to override the method in the interface first

Comment: @TinyOS can you please post your solution (code) - so i can understand much better?

Comment: Hi iDevApps, just want to confirm that you are passing 1234 as jobClassCd when you are hitting the API

Comment: I am creating my own api .  and yes.

Comment: Your question contradicts with the title. Rephrase the question and make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity mapping for jobClassCd refers to an @Id which will 'mute' other records with the same value. Either include 'rateType' into composite Id or have a (separate column) sequenced based @Id

Answer (score 0):

To summerize, in spring data you can use `findBy` plus the field that can be your condition and of course you can have multiple conditions like : `findByField1AndField2` etc.. 
You can find out more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

For you example you can do :

```
    @Repository // you can remove the annotation
    public interface SalaryRepository extends CrudRepository<Salary, String> {

        List<Salary> findByJobClassCd(String jobClassCd);

        List<Salary> findByRateType(String rateType);

    }
```

PS: Then in the business layer you can convert the list to stream or else

Comment: and then in my SalaryService - can I do `public List<Salary> findByRateType(String rateType)`? and the following implementation like I did with retrieveSalary?

Comment: in the retrieveAllSalaries() method you can do : `salaryRepository.findByRateType(param).stream();`